# Recursively add digits

Tags: c#, recursion

I'm going through a problem on LeetCode and need a refresher on recursion. This is the question:

```
Given a non-negative integer num, repeatedly add all its digits until 
the result has only one digit.

For example:

Given num = 38, the process is like: 3 + 8 = 11, 1 + 1 = 2. Since 2 has only one digit, 
return it.
```

I've seen answers using while loops but I would like to try this with recursion. 
This is what I have so far:

```
public int AddDigits(int num) {
    if(num > 9)
    {
        num = (num%10) + (num/10);
        AddDigits(num);
    }
    else{
        return num;
    }
}
```

First, I get `"Not all code paths return a value."` but based on the `if` boolean check, shouldn't this be okay? Even if I add a `return num` after the else block, I still get 11. Using an input of 29, my solution returns 11, even though `num`eventually becomes 2. With my recursive solution above, the `return num` portion occurs several times (I tested with Console.WriteLine statements) - is this due to the stack?

Here's what I would like to know - why does code occur after a recursive call - or should recursive calls typically NOT include code after the recursive call?

Also, how can I get this to work with recursion and without the use of while loops?

Comment: `return AddDigits(num);`

Comment: "why does code occur after a recursive call - or should recursive calls typically NOT include code after the recursive call?" Look up the term "tail recursion" to find the answer here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a hint, won't produce the correct value but it will get you there.

(Another hint, your function needs to take two arguments)

```
public int AddDigits(int num) {
    if(num > 9)
    {
        num = (num%10) + (num/10);
        return AddDigits(num);
    }
    else{
        return num;
    }
}
```

**Edit:** Solution in Python

```
def ra(n):
  if n > 0:
    return n % 10 + ra(n / 10)
  else:
    return 0
```

Comment: "your function needs to take two arguments"? I don't see why.

Comment: Well naturally this will only work for 2 digit numbers but even for 3+ you can do it with 1 parameter.

Comment: @NickA interesting, didn't think of using the stack to hold the residual values. I've updated my answer with such an algorithm.

Comment: is there sum math over here? I was surprised to see this actually works. hmmm going to check

Comment: _won't produce the correct value_. no! it _does_ produce a correct value. if you believe my algorithm works you can check it against yours. loop from `0` to `int.Max` and throw exception if result of my algorithm was different than yours. you will never get exception !

Answer (score 3):

You need to return value in both path's (if and else).

it *could* be this (changing `AddDigits(num);` to `return AddDigits(num);` also works (given in other answer), btw I don't know why, but It works)

```
public int AddDigits(int num, bool root = true) {
    if(num > 9)
    {
        var sum = num;

        if(root)
        {
            while(sum > 9)
            {
                sum = AddDigits(sum/10, false) + sum%10;
            }
            return sum;
        }
        else return AddDigits(num/10, false) + num%10;
    }
    else{
        return num;
    }
}
```

Call function like this

```
var result = AddDigits(123456789); // ;)
```

This is how the algorithm works.

```
       AddDigits(123456789)   (root of call)         45   (45 is bigger than 9.    AddDigits(45)     9 is not bigger than 9. return result.
                    ||                               /\   repeat. while(sum > 9))       ||           /\
                    \/                               ||                                 \/           ||
   9 + AddDigits(12345678)                           ||                            4 + AddDigits(5)= 9     
                    ||                               ||
                    \/                      9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1 = 45
9 + 8 + AddDigits(1234567)                           ||
                    ||                               ||
                   ....                              ||        
                    ||                               ||
                    \/                               ||
            9+8+7+6+5+4+3+2+1 (now going back and summing them all)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using Linq:

```
using System.Linq;

static int Singularize(int val)
{
  string str=val.ToString();
  int rslt=Enumerable.Range(0,str.Length).Select(i => str.Substring(i,1)).Select(int.Parse).Sum();
  return (rslt.ToString().Length==1) ? rslt : Singularize(rslt);
}
```

Returning the recursion call itself (when necessary) allows the CLR to leave the current call and move to the recursive call and reuse the same stack item.  If you retain the current call (by making the recursive call return it's result to the current call) each call in the recursive chain will lump another straw on the camel's (stacks) back, until the camel breaks - i.e., a stack overflow error.

Answer (score 1):

So really two different operations, both of which can be stated recursively.

Operation 1 is to add all the digits of a number together:

```
int AddAllDigits(int n)
{
    return n < 10 ? n : (n % 10 + AddAllDigits(n / 10));
}
```

Operation 2 is to keep performing operation 1 until we only have a single digit:

```
int ReduceToSingleDigit(int n)
{
    return n < 10 ? n : ReduceToSingleDigit(AddAllDigits(n));
}
```

So now we can

```
ReduceToSingleDigit(123456789); //gives 9
```

Now, if we have available the goodness of C#6, we can make our recursive functions look a bit more stylish (or confusing, depending on your position) by reducing them to expression bodies instead of statement bodies.

```
int ReduceToSingleDigit(int n) => n < 10 ? n : ReduceToSingleDigit(AddDigits(n));

int AddDigits(int n) => n < 10 ? n : (n % 10 + AddDigits(n / 10));
```

Lovely.